# Module is not available,but with correct module name and load it

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

I am so confused to dependency injection in AngularJS. Recently, I meet an error that I can not solve it. I suspect something misunderstanding and misuse in dependency injection. 
Here is my code:

```
In file A.js
var CustomerModel = angular.module('myCustomer',['ngResource','LoginController']);
In file B.js
CustomerModel
    .controller('LoginController', LoginController);
```

My error is:

Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myCustomer due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module LoginController due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'LoginController' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

According to the problem and error, I come out with a question. Can a controller(LoginController) is injected in a module(myCustomer) in angularJS? Is this the reason that cause such error?

Comment: You're passing the controller as a dependency to your module, the controller doesn't exist yet. change your file A to be `var CustomerModel = angular.module('myCustomer',['ngResource']);`

Comment: `LoginController` is not a module. It is just a controller, so you don't have to lay that dependency

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LoginController` is not a module. It is just a controller, so you don't need to lay a dependency on that one. Just remove it:

```
// only lay dependency on other angular modules
// angular modules are the ones that are registered as 'angular.module('module name', [deps or empty array])'
var CustomerModel = angular.module('myCustomer', [
    'ngResource',
]);


// register the controller, not a module
CustomerModel
    .controller('LoginController', LoginController);
```